# Mysql 5.5 spatial to Google Maps API

Tags: geojson, spatial-database, google-maps-api, mysql-spatial

I've got a mysql table with points and polygons spatial geometries.

I can see that MySQL 5.5 doesn't have the `ST_AsGeoJSON()` function to extract to GeoJSON.

I'm looking for the simplest way to load these geometries to Google Maps API.

Before starting to read data in PHP and put them in an array structure and send it in GeoJSON format, I wonder if there is a simplest way to do it.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it: query the data from MySQL with PHP, parse the data to geoJSON (or JSON or XML) format, then display on Google Maps.